# How to move a child object towards another coordinates?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I create child objects (cubes) under my player (after he "jump" to made space for new objects), first child is attached normal, but other cubes are created in position of first child (something like cube in cube). How to сreate children objects so that they are created one above the other at axis Y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html), setting the parent and setting the position relative to the parent's position.

```
[SerializeField] int objectsToCreate = 3;
[SerializeField] GameObject objToClone;
[SerializeField] Transform rootObjInScene;
[SerializeField] float distance = 20f;

void Awake()
{
    Transform curParent = rootObjInScene;
    Vector posOffset = Vector3.up * distance;

    for (int i = 0; i < objectsToCreate; i++)
    {
        Vector3 newPos = curParent.position + posOffset;
        GameObject newObj = Instantiate(objToClone, newPos, Quaternion.identity, 
                curParent);

        curParent = newObj.transform;
    }
}
```

Or, to create one at a time:

```
[SerializeField] int objectsToCreate = 3;
[SerializeField] GameObject objToClone;
[SerializeField] Transform rootObjInScene;
[SerializeField] float distance = 20f;

Transform curParent;
Vector3 posOffset;

void Awake()
{
    curParent = rootObjInScene;
    posOffset = Vector3.up * distance;
}

public void CreateAnother()
{
    Vector3 newPos = curParent.position + posOffset;
    GameObject newObj = Instantiate(objToClone, newPos, Quaternion.identity, 
            curParent);

    curParent = newObj.transform;
}
```

Comment: Works, thanks a lot. When the player selects a given item (analogous to a snake, as an example), this code can be called as a condition if{}, right?

Comment: The problem is that I need to add the cube one at a time when the player picks up the required item. That is, initially there is one cube, after them two, then three, four, and so on. However, initially it should be alone.

Comment: @alexandrfandeev The question should be [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66232326/edit) to explain that clearly, because it currentlydoesn't mention anything about any of that... Anyway, I added a version where you can call `CreateAnother` whenever you want to instantiate once.